# Understanding Richardson's Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logic, algorithms, symbolic-computation

[Richardson's Theorem](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RichardsonsTheorem.html) states that (quoting from Wolfram MathWorld):

> Let $\mathcal{R}$ be the class of expressions generated by
>
> 1. The rational numbers and the two real numbers $\pi$ and $\ln 2$,
> 2. The variable $x$,
> 3. The operations of addition, multiplication, and composition, and
> 4. The sine, exponential, and absolute value functions.
>
> Then if $E \in \mathcal{R}$, the predicate "$E=0$" is recursively undecidable.

I'm not sure if I understand this correctly. It seems that I can select for example:

- $\sin(x) \in \mathcal{R}$
- $1 - \sin(x)^2 - \cos(x)^2 \in \mathcal{R}$

For the first choice, it is clear that $E\equiv 0$ is false while for the second choice, it is clear that $E\equiv 0$ is true. Both expressions are contained in the set $\mathcal{R}$, so I don't understand how the theorem can state that these are undecidable.

Comment: The point is that you must it decide for EVERY possible expression

Comment: The theorem states that every algorithm trying to decide whether we have $E=0$ will fail for some expression , that is it will give a wrong answer for some expression.

Comment: @Peter In this case, shouldn't the theorem state that $\exists E \in \mathcal{R}$ s.t. $E \equiv 0$ is undecidable? To my understanding its current formulation implies that $E \in \mathcal{R} \Rightarrow E \equiv 0 \; \mathrm{undecidable}$ and since there are no restrictions on $E$ given, this should hold $\forall E \in \mathcal{R}$.

Comment: It's poorly phrased. Keep in mind that it doesn't make sense to ask whether a single yes/no question is algorithmically undecidable (any finite amount of information is algorithmically decidable, we just might not know what algorithm does the job). Note that [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richardson%27s_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem) does better.

Comment: For any computer program, there is a corresponding algebraic expression (this conversion consists of many steps, each fairly straightforward) such that that expression is identically $0$ iff the computer program doesn't (?) halt.